# How can I combine a Qscrollbar with the Qfiledialog?

Tags: android, qt

I encountered a problem when I am developing an app on android platform using QT. I enlarged the fontsize of Qfiledialog component, but the mobile screen is too small to show all parts of QFiledialog. I need a Qscrollbar to adjust a position and select a folder. How can I combine a qscrollbar with the Qfiledialog or can I only enlarge the font size within the area bounded by a red line as below?

[image]

**My source code:**

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{    
    this->setStyleSheet("QFileDialog QWidget {font: 20pt \"Arial\";}"); //    QFileDialog    

    QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this,QString(),"/mnt/sdcard/test/",QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);

    model = new QFileSystemModel();
    filesPath = dir;
    model->setRootPath(dir);
    QStringList filter;
    filter <<"*.png" <<"*.jpg" <<"*.bmp" <<"*.gif";
    model->setNameFilters(filter);
    model->setNameFilterDisables(false);
```

I tried the following code. The fontsize of QTreeView can be enlarged in desktop mode as I expected, but fails to work on the mobile.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{  
    this->setStyleSheet("QFileDialog QTreeView {font: 30pt \"Arial\";}"); //    QFileDialog    

    QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this,QString(),"/mnt/sdcard/test/",QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);

    model = new QFileSystemModel();
    filesPath = dir;
    model->setRootPath(dir);
    QStringList filter;
    filter <<"*.png" <<"*.jpg" <<"*.bmp" <<"*.gif";
    model->setNameFilters(filter);
    model->setNameFilterDisables(false);
```

Comment: Its not recommended to use Qt c++ for user interfaces, rather Qt QML is the generally accepted style.